# HTML - JavaScript - Tag element showing null

Tags: javascript, html

why is my `let list = document.querySelector('.list')` list variable showing as `null` when in reality there is a ul tag with the class property of `list`?

```
***ToDoApp/script.js***
let list = document.querySelector('.list')
console.log(list)
const CHECK = {status:'completed', icon:'bx bxs-check-circle'};
const UNCHECK = {status:'not-completed', icon:'bx bx-circle'}
let id = 0;

let itemsList = []
```

```
***data-include-html.min.js file***
$(function(){
  $("*[data-include-html]").each(function(){
    var t = $(this).attr("data-include-html"),
        u = this.id;
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: t,
          success: function(t){
            $("#" + u).html(t)
          },
          error: function(n, c, i){
            var s = n.status + ": " + n.statusText;
            $("#" + u).html(t + "-" + s)
          }
        })
  })
});
```

```
***MAIN HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To Do</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./ToDoApp/style.css">
  <!-- Boxicons CDN Link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>

<div data-include-html="./ToDoApp/index.html" id="todo-app"></div>
</div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="include-html.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./ToDoApp/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
***To Do HTM File***

    <div class="container" id="todo-app">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="clear">
          <i class="bx bx-refresh"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="date"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="items-content">
          <ul class="list" id="list">
          
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="add-item">
            <i class="bx bxs-plus-circle"></i>
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add a to-do">
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: your *data-include-html* creating issue  (***MAIN HTML), check this

Comment: Please see edited code. I added the data-include-html code to this post

Answer (score 0):

First, I adjusted the *.querySelector* to target *#list* instead of *.list*. This will target the individual list element rather than looking for multiple elements.

```js
let list = document.querySelector('#list')
```

When I ran the snippet, this was the output from my console:

```html
 <ul class="list" id="list">
          
 </ul>
```

If your console is coming up as null, this may because there are no elements inside of the "#list" parent element.

Comment: Its still coming up as null. As vasish hayat mentioned above, could it be my data-include-html.min.js file? I edited my post by adding that code to the post as well

Comment: @night_programmer I believe so since I received no issues while running the code without 'data-include-html.min.js'.

Answer (score 0):

Your `script.js` is loading before `index.html`, so at the time the script runs no `.list` element exists yet.

You can probably solve it by including the script tag in the `index.html` instead of `main.html`.

```
<div class="container" id="todo-app">
  <div class="header">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Or add another attribute, like `data-include-html-callback`, and use it in the `include-html.js` to call a function in `script.js`

```
$(function(){
  $("*[data-include-html]").each(function(){
    var t = $(this).attr("data-include-html"),
        c = $(this).attr("data-include-html-callback"),
        u = this.id;
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: t,
          success: function(t){
            $("#" + u).html(t);
            if (typeof window[c] == 'function') window[c]();
          },
          error: function(n, c, i){
            var s = n.status + ": " + n.statusText;
            $("#" + u).html(t + "-" + s);
          }
        })
  })
});

function onTodoLoad(){
    let list = document.querySelector('.list')
    console.log("list:" + list);
    const CHECK = {status:'completed', icon:'bx bxs-check-circle'};
    const UNCHECK = {status:'not-completed', icon:'bx bx-circle'}
    let id = 0;
    let itemsList = []
}

  <div data-include-html="index.html" data-include-html-callback="onTodoLoad" id="todo-app"></div>
```

I didn't really test any of these solutions, so you probably will have to adapt them.

Edit: [Second solution worked fine for me](https://github.com/Gunterbergg/include-html-test).

Comment: I got the following error. ```GET http://127.0.0.1:54474/client/include-html.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)``` I didnt realize its that much of a headache to include one html file in another. Its been hours and I cant figure it out.

Comment: In my project I've changed the paths so I didn't have to mimic your file structure, this error just means that `include-html.min.js` is not in the folder you specified. If you're hours on the same problem taking a break might help

Comment: is there a way I can do all this using javascript and not jquery?

Comment: Yes, there certainly is, you can use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or the [xhr api](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to achieve the same result

Comment: Oh okay I see. Will the fetch api go in the script tag of the main html file? When the response arrives successfully I can use DOMparser()?

Comment: You would use the fetch api to substitute the `include-html.min.js` so you don't' have to use JQuery, when the response arrives you can use any method you prefer to insert the response into the HTML, DOMParser is a good example.

Comment: Ok gotcha. Thanks. Lastly - will I still need to bring in the css and script file of the html file I’m fetching into the main html also?

Comment: You can but you don't need to do it yourself, if the html you fetch contains `<script>` and `<link>` tags referencing valid files the browser will download and apply those automatically as soon as the tags are included in the DOM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239340/discussion-between-gunther-and-night-programmer).